# Passing values without keys in the url when submitting a form

Tags: php, html

My form has 2 textboxes and 1 button.

When submitting my form, I'd like the url to be similar to this www.differentdomain.com/aa00/bb00 instead of www.differentdomain.com/?q1=aa00&q2=bb00

Here is my html code:

```
<form action="https://differentdomain.com/" id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off">
<input class="fs-anim-lower"  id="q1" type="text" placeholder="aa00" required/>
<input class="fs-anim-lower" id="q2" type="text" placeholder="bb00" required/>           
<button id="submit" class="fs-submit" type="submit">see result</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your question? What errors do you get? Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: I am getting the url as www.differentdomain.com/?q1=aa00&q2=bb00

Comment: _I am getting the url as www.differentdomain.com/?q1=aa00&q2=bb00_ Once again: **What is your question?**

Comment: sorry for my inappropriate words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question right, you can do something like this using `jQuery`:

```
$('form#myform').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var urlData = '';
    // order is very important so that you can recognize each value
    urlData += '/' + $(this).find('#q1').val();
    urlData += '/' + $(this).find('#q2').val();

    $.get(domain + urlData, function (data) { alert('success'); });
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: It makes ajax request instead of async for submission that op used in his example.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be to change form action every time its fields change:

```
document.querySelector('#myform').addEventListener('input', function () {
    this.action = this.q1.value + '/' + this.q2.value
})
```